# Subset data frame based on condition of multiple months and years in R?

Tags: r

The attached is the data frame I am dealing with.

[image: data frame]

The first column in the data frame is the Date. I have to subset data frame based on condition on multiple months and years. For example, I want all July and September months data for the years 2005 and 2006.

I tried following code:

```r
output <- subset(df, format.Date(Date, "%m")==c("07", "09") & format.Date(Date, "%Y")==c("2005","2006"))
```

The above code results the unexpected output.

I found posts regarding this problem but those were only for single month and year.

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: Use %in% rather than == .  Also you should not, in general, refer to methods directly.  Use the genreic so format.Date should be format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind installing `tidyverse` package, you can use this simple filtering:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)  # should come with tidyverse, no need to install it separately

# filter July and September data in 2005 and 2006
output <- df %>%
    filter(year(Date) %in% c(2005, 2006) & month(Date) %in% c(7, 9))
```

If you want to use base R, this should work as well:

```
output <- subset(df, format(Date, "%m") %in% c("07", "09") & format(Date, "%Y") %in% c("2005", "2006"))
```

in case that class of `df$Date` column is `"Date"`.

Comment: Thanks @raghav for your feedback, I'm glad it works! I have added a base R solution, which is however more difficult to read, so for basic computations I certainly recommend using tidyverse & lubridate.